# Integrating Hbase with Hive: Register Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox 2.0 which contains the following version of Hbase and Hive

```
Component       Version
------------------------
Apache Hadoop     2.2.0
Apache Hive      0.12.0
Apache HBase     0.96.0
Apache ZooKeeper  3.4.5
```

...and
I am trying to register my hbase table into hive using the following query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Document_Table_Hive (key STRING, author STRING, category STRING) STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’ WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (‘hbase.columns.mapping’ = ‘:key,metadata:author,categories:category’) TBLPROPERTIES (‘hbase.table.name’ = ‘Document’);
```

This does not work, I get the following Exception:

```
2014-03-26 09:14:57,341 ERROR exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:execute(435)) – java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.setConf(HBaseStorageHandler.java:249)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)

2014-03-26 09:14:57,368 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) – FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

I have already created the Hbase Table “Document” and the describe command gives the following description

```
‘Document’,
{NAME => ‘categories’,..},
{NAME => ‘comments’,..},
{NAME => ‘metadata’,..}
```

I have tried the following things

1. add hive.aux.jars.path in hive-site.xml

   ```
   hive.aux.jars.path
   file:///etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.96.0.2.0.6.0-76-hadoop2.jar,file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.12.0.2.0.6.0-76.jar,file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.0.2.0.6.0-76-hadoop2.jar,file:///usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-76.jar
   ```
2. add jars using hive add jar command

   ```
   add jar /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.96.0.2.0.6.0-76-hadoop2.jar;
   add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.12.0.2.0.6.0-76.jar;
   add jar /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.0.2.0.6.0-76-hadoop2.jar;
   add jar /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-76.jar;
   add file /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
   ```
3. specify the hadoop_classpath

   ```
   export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.96.0.2.0.6.0-76-hadoop2:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-76.jar
   ```

And it is still not working!

How can I add the jars in the hive classpath so that it finds the hbaseConfiguration class,
or is it an entirely different issue?

Comment: Try copy hbase-common-*.jar to hive lib /usr/lib/hive/lib/

Comment: i did copy the jar. then it asked for other jar

Comment: cp /usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/

with no overwrite.

Now i am getting 
2014-03-28 03:03:37,506 ERROR exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:execute(435)) - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface

which jar i need to include ?

Comment: finally it works!
copied the jars from Hadoop too.
and copied the hbase and hadoop conf to /etc/Hive/conf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to copy the entire jars. Just `hbase-*.jar , zookeeper*.jar, hive-hbase-handler*.jar` would be enough. By default all hadoop related jars would be added to hadoop classpath, Since hive internally uses hadoop command to execute.

Or

Instead of copying hbase jars to hive library by specifying `HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH` environment variable to /usr/lib/hbase/lib/ in /etc/hive/conf/hive-env.sh will also do.

The second approach is more suggested than first

Comment: Does the second option also work when configured in hive-site.xml?

Comment: Using * doesn't work well with HIVE 1.2.1+TEZ+Hadoop 2.6.0. I recommend to give a list of jar instead.