# Register Hbase table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox 2.1. This Version contains Hbase and Hive.
In order to register my hbase table into hive: i fallowed this link :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

```
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test_Hive (key int, valuer string) STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’ WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (‘hbase.columns.mapping’ = ‘:key,cf1:val’) TBLPROPERTIES (‘hbase.table.name’ = ‘table_test’);'
```

But i've got this error :

```
'Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.q1.exec.DDLtask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.q1.metadata.HiveException : Error in Loading storage handler.org.apashe.hadoop.hive.hbase.HbaseStorageHandler'
```

I've found in this link :
[Integrating Hbase with Hive: Register Hbase table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688660/hbase-integration-with-hive-register-hbase-table-in-hive)

That i should copie all the jars from Hbase and haddop to hive. And copie the hbase and hadoop conf to /etc/Hive/conf/ like this :

```
'cp -n /usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/ 
 cp -n /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/
 cp -n /usr/lib/hbase/conf/* /usr/lib/hive/conf/
 cp -n /usr/lib/hadoop/conf/* /usr/lib/hive/conf/'
```

But it still not working !!!!
Then i've tried another solution that consist in(also found in the link above) :
"Or
Instead of copying hbase jars to hive library by specifying HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH environment variable to /usr/lib/hbase/lib/ in /etc/hive/conf/hive-env.sh will also do. "

So i've edited my "/hive-env.sh" file to change the HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH  like this :

```
'export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH= /usr/lib/hbase/lib'
```

And it still not working !!
Can you please show me how to fix this problem ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
```

2)CLOSE HBASE AND HADOOP USING FOLLOWING COMMOND

```
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
/usr/lib/hbase/bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

3) RESTART HBASE AND HADOOP USING COMMOND

```
 /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you've wrote the same commande "sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/" twice.. is it normal ?